# TypeDoc and how to exclude *.d.ts files only from few paths

Tags: regex, typescript, gruntjs, documentation, typedoc

I've got the next question about TypeDoc.
So I have got a TypeDoc config like that:

```
typedoc: {
    build: {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../MyDocumentation/',
            name: 'MyApp',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: '**/*/*.d.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            ...some sources...
        ]
    }
}
```

On my app are a few paths with *.ts files. After recompiled those files the *.d.ts files had been created and I want to exclude it.

So for needs of this question we'll assume that my paths looks like that:

- MyApp/Scripts/FolderA/ (there are a few *.ts files, for example: fileA.ts)
- MyApp/Scripts/FolderB/ (there are a few *.ts files, for example: fileB.ts)
- MyApp/Scripts/FolderC/ (there are a few *.ts files, for example: fileC.ts)

Now my TypeDoc config is excluding all *.d.ts files from full of app.

I'm trying to exclude *.d.ts files but only from a my defined paths so I was trying a few ways to define my exclude pattern:

1. `exclude: 'Scripts/{FolderA,FolderB,FolderC}/*.d.ts'` but it is just ignoring
2. `exclude: '**/*+(FolderA|FolderB|FolderC)/*.d.ts'` but I've got a `Process terminated with code 3. 'FolderB' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` error.
3. `exclude: '**/{FolderA,FolderB,FolderC}/*.d.ts'` but it is just ignoring too
4. ```
   exclude: [
       'Scripts/FolderA/*.d.ts',
       'Scripts/FolderB/*.d.ts',
       'Scripts/FolderC/*.d.ts'
   ]
   ```

   but it are ignoring too...
5. `**/FolderA/*.d.ts` is not ignoring but how to add a few path? Some of my path have a subfolders, ex. `**/FolderA/ver1/*.d.ts`

And that's all because I need to include to my documentation all `index.d.ts` files from `node_modules`. I need to reference to those libs.

Maybe there is another way how to do it?

I saw [this comment](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/170#issuecomment-326245683) but I don't know why - my typedoc recompiling task is ignoring that pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found answer by myself...again  !

I need something like that:

```
exclude: [
    '**/FolderA/*.d.ts',
    '**/FolderA/ver1/*.d.ts',
    '**/FolderB/*.d.ts',
    '**/FolderC/*.d.ts'
]
```

now I have to way how to include only `index.d.ts` files from `node_module` :D

---

It was a piece of cake - I need to add into `src` line: `'node_modules/*/index.d.ts'`